# Uploading React app on Github Pages: how to skip the uploading of the node modules folder?

Tags: java, html, reactjs, github, npm

I have been trying to upload on my Github pages a normal React app but everytime it takes literally ages to upload the node modules folder with all those dependecies. I tried to upload only the build folder (minified version) but it is not working, probably because the package.json file with the strings pointing at my Github folder is in the non-minified folder.
Is there a way to skip the uploading of the node_modules folder?
Also, can you please point out a good tutorial on how to correctly upload the React app on Github?

Comment: with gitignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a .gitignore file and put node_modules there.

Here is an example of .gitignore to react-gh-pages: [.gitignore](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/blob/master/.gitignore)